# How to create a vector (array) of matrices?

Tags: octave

I'm a beginner with Octave, and would like to know how create 
an `n` length vector of matrices `m_1, m_2, ..., m_n`, where each `m_i` has the same dimensions.

Basically, I'd like to do something like this with a function 
called `vector_of_matrices` -- if any similar such function in Octave 
exists:

```
vm = vector_of_matrices( [ rand(2,3) ; ones(2,3) ]
vm(2) == ones(2,3)   % this should be '1' or 'true'
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two "native" approaches come to my mind: (a) using a cell array, or (b) using a 3-dimensional array. Both do not fully satisfy your desired behavior:

```matlab
m1 = rand(3, 2)
m2 = ones(3, 2)
m3 = eye(3, 2)

% Approach #1: Cell array
vm = { m1, m2, m3 }
vm{2} == ones(3, 2)

% Approach #2: 3-dimensional array
vm = cat(3, m1, m2, m3)                % Thanks to Cris Luengo for this tweak
vm(:, :, 2) == ones(3, 2)
```

Using a cell array almost has the desired behavior, the only difference is, that you have to use `{}` to "index" the proper element, because `()` will just return the corresponding cell, but `{}` returns its content. Also, with cell arrays, it's not necessary that all matrices have the same dimensions. Personally, that would be my favorite here.

The 3-dimensional array also works fine, but seems quite complicated to generalize. Using anonymous functions, the generation could be simplified, like so:

```matlab
vector_of_matrices = @(varargin) cat(3, varargin{:});
vm = vector_of_matrices(m1, m2, m3)
```

Nevertheless, you can't override the `()` (`subsindex`) operator globally, because that'd affect all array accessing.

If you explicitly want to have the described behavior, you can set up a class `vector_of_matrices`, internally implemented - for example - using approach #1, and setting up / overriding the `()` operator.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was thinking that your custom class idea is not a lot of work -- it could be done in a few lines of code. But in MATLAB you can never do `vm(1)(3,4)`. The parser does not accept two sets of parentheses in a row. So the class would be quite limited in capabilities. A cell array is so much easier to use. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Since the question is specifically about Octave, there's no need to be considerate of MATLAB users here, I guess. I'd be happy to see a class implemention from you, since I never worked with them and short, but complete examples are always a benefit (I'm looking at you, Octave documentation).

Comment: Are you saying that Octave does allow that syntax?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ah - your comment sounded like it's possible in Octave, but not in MATLAB. I did the following test now: `vm_access = @(x) vm(:, :, x), vm_access(1)(2, 2)`. That works!

Comment: @HansHirse - did not know about cell arrays.. thnx for the tip.